# Multi-label image classification with a model train for multi-class classification?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, multilabel-classification

I am currently working through this kaggle project here to preform a multi image classification of white blood cells (There are 4 classes: Neutrophils, Eosinophils, Lymphocytes and Monocytes).

- https://www.kaggle.com/paultimothymooney/blood-cells

Classifying one type of white blood cell is pretty straight forward. I built the model using a CNN from keras. I want to take this problem one step further and try to implement this model in a multi-label image classification.

For example if I feed in this image to my model: https://webpath.med.utah.edu/jpeg5/HEME002.jpg
I want my model to output the presence of white blood cells, in this case it should output "Neutrophils and Lymphocytes present."

The problem with this is that all the images in this dataset are images with a SINGLE white blood cell and that is what the model is trained on. It is never seen an image with more then ONE white blood cell in it.

My question is it possible to take this model and some how extrapolate it to work with an image with more then one type of white blood cell?

I will be using this code here:

```
bnmomemtum=0.85
def fire(x, squeeze, expand):
  y  = Conv2D(filters=squeeze, kernel_size=1, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
  y  = BatchNormalization(momentum=bnmomemtum)(y)
  y1 = Conv2D(filters=expand//2, kernel_size=1, activation='relu', padding='same')(y)
  y1 = BatchNormalization(momentum=bnmomemtum)(y1)
  y3 = Conv2D(filters=expand//2, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same')(y)
  y3 = BatchNormalization(momentum=bnmomemtum)(y3)
  return concatenate([y1, y3])

def fire_module(squeeze, expand):
  return lambda x: fire(x, squeeze, expand)

x = Input(shape=[IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3])
y = BatchNormalization(center=True, scale=False)(x)
y = Activation('relu')(y)
y = Conv2D(kernel_size=5, filters=12, padding='same', use_bias=True, activation='relu')(x)
y = BatchNormalization(momentum=bnmomemtum)(y)

y = fire_module(12, 24)(y)
y = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(y)

y = fire_module(24, 48)(y)
y = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(y)

y = fire_module(32, 64)(y)
y = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(y)

y = fire_module(24, 48)(y)
y = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(y)

y = fire_module(18, 36)(y)
y = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(y)

y = fire_module(12, 24)(y)

y = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(y)
y = Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='sigmoid')(y)
model = Model(x, y)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=2e-5),
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
```